# Why can I not see the property Local when using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, data-binding

I know I am missing something completely obvious, but why can't I see the property `Local` when working with an EF context? The typical example online looks like the following:

`context.Parents.Local`

But I am unable to see the `Local` property. Now from what I understand, Local is a member of the DbSet class, and I don't think I'm working with a DbSet in my application. What I do know is I've added a reference to the EntityFramework, have `using System.Data.Entity` and everything else I'm familiar with doing is working just fine. Except `Local` isn't there, and I really do need some sorting capability for my `DataGridView`.

Help!

Comment: Is `Local` a column in your database (hence a property of your entity)? Is `Parents` a table in your database (hence an entity) or an association?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at your auto-generated code for the context class, does it inherit from DbContext or ObjectContext?

If it is inheriting from ObjectContext, there are a few more steps you need to take.

- On the model design surface, Right Click->Add Code Generation Item
- Select 'Code' from the menu on the left
- Select 'ADO.NET DbContextGenerator'
- Name the item the same as your model (ex: 'MyModel')
- Click Add

Two *.tt files will be added to your project called something like MyModel.tt and MyModel.Context.tt.

After a recompile, look at your auto-generated code for the context again and it should now inherit from DbContext.  Your Parents object will now be of type DbSet instead of ObjectSet and you will now be able to use the Local property.

Comment: I probably should have updated this question, but this was what I needed to do. I didn't even have the ADO.NET DbContext add-in installed and no code was generated using it. Once I had this, all was well.

Answer (score 4):

`DbContext`, `DbSet` etc. are part Entity Framework 4.1/4.2 which is shipped, among others, as the EntityFramework NuGet package. With just the .NET Framework you only have what is now called "Core EF Runtime" according to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/08/09/ef-releases-amp-versioning-call-for-feedback.aspx):

In short, you need to install EF 4.1/4.2.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is what I'm missing. Thanks!

Comment: It seems I spoke to soon. I already had Entity Framework installed from NuGet, but I figured I may have the wrong version. I installed version 4.2 and I still don't have the Local property available. Am I missing a `using` clause? As I said earlier, I have `using System.Data.Entity`...

Comment: If I had references to both EntityFramework and System.Data.Entity, would it cause a conflict? I'm positive I have the latest version of EF installed but the property still isn't visible.

Comment: Does it matter that my model was created using "database first"?

Comment: Just adding the reference to the NuGet package won't do it. You need to have the supporting C# code generated so that it uses the "simplified" DbContext/DbSet APIs instead of the "core" ObjectContext/ObjectSet. The T4 template to do so should be included with EF 4.2.