# Does EF caching work differently for SQL Server CE 3.5?

Tags: entity-framework

I have been developing some single-user desktop apps using Entity Framework and SQL Server 3.5.  I thought I had read somewhere that once records are in an EF cache for one context, if they are deleted using a different context, they are not removed from the cache for the first context even when a new query is executed.  Hence, I've been writing really inefficient and obfuscatory code so I can dispose the context and instantiate a new one whenever another method modifies the database using its own context.

I recently discovered some code where I had not re-instantiated the first context under these conditions, but it worked anyway.  I wrote a simple test method to see what was going on:

```
        using (UnitsDefinitionEntities context1 = new UnitsDefinitionEntities())
        {
            List<RealmDef> rdl1 = (from RealmDef rd in context1.RealmDefs
                                   select rd).ToList();
            RealmDef rd1 = RealmDef.CreateRealmDef(100, "TestRealm1", MeasurementSystem.Unknown, 0);
            context1.RealmDefs.AddObject(rd1);
            context1.SaveChanges();
            int rd1ID = rd1.RealmID;

            using (UnitsDefinitionEntities context2
                = new UnitsDefinitionEntities())
            {
                RealmDef rd2 = (from RealmDef r in context2.RealmDefs
                                where r.RealmID == rd1ID select r).Single();
                context2.RealmDefs.DeleteObject(rd2);
                context2.SaveChanges();
                rd2 = null;
            }

            rdl1 = (from RealmDef rd in context1.RealmDefs select rd).ToList();
```

Setting a breakpoint at the last line I was amazed to find that the added and deleted entity was in fact **not** returned by the second query on the first context!

I several possible explanations:

1. I am totally mistaken in my understanding that the cached records
   are not removed upon requerying.
2. EF is capricious in its caching and it's a matter of luck.
3. Caching has changed in EF 4.1.
4. The issue does not arise when the two contexts are
   instantiated in the same process.
5. Caching works differently for SQL CE 3.5 than other versions of SQL
   server.

I suspect the answer may be one of the last two options.  I would really rather not have to deal with all the hassles in constantly re-instantiating contexts for single-user desktop apps if I don't have to do so.

Can I rely on this discovered behavior for single-user desktop apps using SQL CE (3.5 and 4)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run the 2nd query on an the ObjectSet it's requerying the database, which is why it's reflecting the change exposed by your 2nd context.   Before we go too far into this, are you sure you want to have 2 contexts like you're explaining?  Contexts should be short lived, so it might be better if you're caching your list in memory or doing something else of that nature.

That being said, you can access the local store by calling `ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries` and viewing what is in the store there.  However, what you're probably looking for is the .Local storage that's provided by DbSets in EF 4.2 and beyond.  See [this blog post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781018.aspx) for more information about that.

Judging by your class names, it looks like you're using an edmx so you'll need to make some changes to your file to have your context inherit from a DbSet to an objectset.   [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075887/why-can-i-not-see-the-property-local-when-using-entity-framework) can show you how

Comment: Mark is basically correct in his analysis of the issue (see my answer). And converting my projects to DbContext is on my agenda. Re. the first comment: Of course the context should be transient for ASP.Net, Silverlight or Metro apps and for apps accessing remote/detached databases. But as an old FoxPro programmer I find it annoying to have to deal with editing detached entities or copied data, then saving back to the database for modest single-user desktop apps with local attached databases. The power and clarity of the object data model is diluted by unnecessarily complex code in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Explanation #1 was closer to the fact.  Inserting the following statement at the end of the example:

```
var cached = context1.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(System.Data.EntityState.Unchanged);
```

revealed that the record was in fact still in the cache.  Mark Oreta was essentially correct in that the database is actually re-queried in the above example.

However, navigational properties apparently behave differently, e.g.:

```
        RealmDef distance = (from RealmDef rd in context1.RealmDefs
                             where rd.Name == "Distance"
                             select rd).Single();
        SystemDef metric = (from SystemDef sd in context1.SystemDefs
                            where sd.Name == "Metric"
                            select sd).Single();
        RealmSystem rs1 = (from RealmSystem rs in distance.RealmSystems
                           where rs.SystemID == metric.SystemID
                           select rs).Single();

        UnitDef ud1 = UnitDef.CreateUnitDef(distance.RealmID, metric.SystemID, 100, "testunit");
        rs1.UnitDefs.Add(ud1);
        context1.SaveChanges();

        using (UnitsDefinitionEntities context2 = new UnitsDefinitionEntities())
        {
            UnitDef ud2 = (from UnitDef ud in context2.UnitDefs
                           where ud.Name == "testunit"
                           select ud).Single();
            context2.UnitDefs.DeleteObject(ud2);
            context2.SaveChanges();
        }

        udList = (from UnitDef ud in rs1.UnitDefs select ud).ToList();
```

In this case, breaking after the last statement reveals that the last query returns the deleted entry from the cache.  This was my source of confusion.

I think I now have a better understanding of what Julia Lerman meant by "Query the model, not the database."  As I understand it, in the previous example I was querying the database.  In this case I am querying the model.  Querying the database in the previous situation happened to do what I wanted, whereas in the latter situation querying the model would not have the desired effect.  (This is clearly a problem with my understanding, not with Julia's advice.)