# C#/SQL: 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet<DatabaseName.TableName> does not contain a definition for 'Local'

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I am attempting to follow the example from Deitel's "C# 2012 for Programmers" from chapter 20 specifically around page 625. I've changed some of the names (my database is "pdxdevinv" instead of "BooksExamples" and my table is "hardwareidtable" rather than "Authors"). Also, I'm using Visual Studio 2010 rather than 2012 because it's what I already own. And I'm using MySQL 6.0.

The problem is that the line:

```
hardwareidtableBindingSource.DataSource = dbcontext.hardwareidtables.Local;
```

Produces this error, complaining that hardwareidtables doesn't have a member named Local:

> Error 1   'System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet' does not contain a definition for 'Local' and no extension method 'Local' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\Users\swade\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\InventoryTracker\DisplayTable\DisplayHardwareTable.cs  38  82  DisplayTable

Here's the whole source file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Validation;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DisplayTable
{
    public partial class DisplayHardwareTable : Form
    {
        public DisplayHardwareTable()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // Entity framework DbContext
        private InventoryTracker.pdxdevinvEntities dbcontext 
                  = new InventoryTracker.pdxdevinvEntities();

        private void DisplayHardwareTable_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // load hardwareidtables table ordered by manufacturer and then hardwareId
            dbcontext.hardwareidtables
                .OrderBy(h => h.manufacturer)
                .ThenBy(h => h.hardwareId)
                .Load();

            // THIS IS THE PROBLEMATIC LINE BELOW

            // specify DataSource 
            hardwareidtableBindingSource.DataSource = dbcontext.hardwareidtables.Local; // .Local????
        }

        private void hardwareidtableBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Validate();
            hardwareidtableBindingSource.EndEdit();

            try
            {
                int ret = dbcontext.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Validation of entered fields failed", "Entity Valid Exception");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

If I remove ".Local" from that line, it builds and runs but will not save any data when the "save" button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

To start off with, the error is stemming from the Local property not found on the DbSet. Now there could be many reasons for this. This has been discussed here.

[Why can I not see the property Local when using Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075887/why-can-i-not-see-the-property-local-when-using-entity-framework)

If this is does not help, please post your EF version and so we can investigate further.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Nico.
The linked post does describe my problem but the instructions don't solve the problem. When I follow the recommended steps, I only get a single 'tt' file, MyModel.tt but no MyModel.Context.tt. Additionally, MyModelModel.cs is created but still inherits from ObjectContext rather than DbContext. Also, MyModelModel.cs conflicts with MyModel.Design.cs but if I delete one I remove the conflicts. Regardless of which one I keep, both are inheriting from the ObjectContext rather than DbContext. 
I do have EF v6 installed and associated with the project.

Comment: EF 6.0.2 to be precise

Answer (score 0):

In the end I decided to completely abandon the use of the Entity Framework. I was never able to get it to use DbContext rather than ObjectContext. I simply fell back to DataSets which are working fine albeit not ideal.

Lesson learned: Unless you have a dire need to use EF for database connectivity, avoid it. It is too complex and temperamental for casual use.